# Can't apt-get update after firewalling with Iptables

Tags: apt, iptables

After I update iptables for my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS, with the following rules:

```
sudo iptables -F 
sudo iptables -X 
sudo iptables -t nat -F 
sudo iptables -t nat -X 
sudo iptables -t mangle -F 
sudo iptables -t mangle -X 
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT 

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 

# Prevent HTTP DOS Attacks
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

# Open Local Loopback
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop Invalid Packets
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# Disallow other traffics
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

The result I can't run apt-get update any more.

Do you have any ideas with this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not allowed a return path for any outgoing traffic initiated by you. You need something like (change eth0 to your interface name):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

By the way this rule:

```
# Prevent HTTP DOS Attacks
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
```

Will never be hit, because you bypassed it with an earlier rule:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

It should have been further restricted by specifying "NEW" state anyhow.

Comment: Do you mean it should be changed to this rule ?   `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT `